# How to show my page when i click link in customer account navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I added link in customer account navigation but how to show my page like Account Dashboard? Thanks.

Like this: [image]

Comment: Here is the detailed answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139004/custom-page-in-my-account/139091#139091

Answer (score 1):

Create a **local.xml** under **app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/layout/**.

Add the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Review -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Reviews</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

It will show in your my account navigation.

For showing navigation on your custom link please update handler in your custom handler like

```
<module_controller_index>
  <update handle="customer_account"/>
  <!-- your code -->
</module_controller_index>
```