# How to create a custom menu in account dashboard in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

How to create  a custom menu in customer account dashboard in magento

[image]

Comment: exact solution available at : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139004/custom-page-in-my-account/139091#139091

Comment: please explain the path of local.xml file @pawan

Comment: @divyasekar check this module : https://github.com/adeshsuryan/add-custom-links-account-navigation-menu

Comment: thank you @RakeshDonga